# Check whether IIS is installed or not?

Tags: iis

I am trying to create a `Local IIS Website` using `ASP.NET`.

When I click on `New -----> Website and select the type as HTTP` and from the dialog box if I select the option as `LOCAL IIS WEBSITE` I am getting a message as "IIS not installed on this computer"

When I checked in the `Control Panel---->Add or remove programs ---->Add or remove windows components`. The Option `Internet Information Service` is already checked marked.

But when I click on the `Control Panel ---> Administrative Tools`, I dont find the option as `Internet Information Service`.

I also have the root directory as `C:\Inetpub\WWWRoot`.

And when I give the following command in the VS command Prompt

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

It is giving the message as finished installing ASP.NET

Can any one help me in identifying whether `IIS` is installed in my system or not?

Please help me out!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

go to `Start->Run` type inetmgr and press OK.  If you get an `IIS` configuration screen.  It is installed, otherwise it isn't.

You can also check `ControlPanel->Add Remove Programs`, Click `Add Remove Windows Components` and look for IIS in the list of installed components.

EDIT

---

To Reinstall IIS.

```
Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs -> Click Add Remove Windows Components
Uncheck IIS box
```

Click next and follow prompts to `UnInstall IIS`.
Insert your windows disc into the appropriate drive.

```
Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs -> Click Add Remove Windows Components
Check IIS box
```

Click next and follow prompts to Install `IIS`.

Comment: If I type the inetmgr in the run command I am getting an error:
"Windows cannot find inetmgr. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again"

But when I look in the second way i have IIS in the Windows Component.

What should I do?

Comment: Un install IIS and ReInstall it.

Comment: Actually one of my friend Installed it into my system. 
And I dont know how to re-install it.
Can you help me out for this please?

Comment: Edited response to include reinstall details.

Comment: note the link phoenix provided is more complete than my quick summary, but it doesn't seem to me that you have any configurations to maintain.

Comment: how can i check this from command line? is it if in system32\appcmd.exe is available that would mean it is already installed???

Comment: inetmgr seems to be a separate installable thing ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723726/missing-inetmgr-exe-file

Answer (score 11):

**For Windows 7:**
Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features On or Off > to turn on IIS click on Check box.

Answer (score 8):

Check

Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> Services --> IIS Admin

For reinstalling

[How to remove and reinstall IIS 5.0, 5.1 and 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325889)

Comment: I dont find any option as SERVICES in my control Panel

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
I dont find any option as IISAdmin in the services list.

Answer (score 7):

In the menu, go to `RUN > services.msc` and hit enter to get the services window and check for the IIS ADMIN service. If it is not present, then reinstall IIS using your windows CD.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of answers here describe how to **manually** check if IIS is installed.

One (of many) **programmatic** ways is to check if the file

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
```

exists, and maybe has a certain minimum version (such as 10.0.0.0 for IIS version 10).

IIS can be [installed programmatically using DISM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54823436/2279059). You can also use DISM to check if IIS is installed, which may be "more correct", but is also more difficult to do than just checking for a file.

**WARNING:** If possible, do not hard-code the path `C:\Windows\System32`, especially not within a 32-bit process or installer, as it can be virtualized and mapped to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, which is NOT where IIS is installed (assuming a 64-bit OS). Depending on where you are implementing your check (installer prerequisites, PowerShell, native code, etc.), there are different ways to explicitly access the 64-bit/native system folder.

Background: `w3wp.exe` is the worker process image of IIS, so if IIS is installed with minimal features, then this file can be expected to exist.

As for version numbers, you can expect the following minimum versions of IIS to be installed in [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services):

- IIS 10 (>= 10.0.0.0) in Windows Server 2016 or higher and Windows 10 or higher
- IIS 8.5 (>= 8.5.0.0) in Windows Server 2012 R2 or higher and Windows 8.1 or higher

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to check is just to write "inetmgr" at run (By pressing Win + R) as a command, if a manager window is appeared then it's installed otherwise it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://localhost:80  (specify port configured)
       OR
http://localhost (default port)
```

type above line in your browser you realize IIS installed or not

Comment: if default site is disabled/removed, this test wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I simple gave below in all my browsers. I got image IIS7

```
http://localhost/
```

Comment: If there's no site configured on port 80, this won't work.

Comment: I guess it will give default IIS page. I may be wrong.

Comment: The default page is generated by a default site. If it's not configured, it won't show. So, it only works if I trust the person who set up the site to have done so sanely.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this a step by step approach:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/365704/Install-IIS-on-Windows

For many users you have to enable the windows feature on then check IIS and then go with RUN followed by searching for inetmgr.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this on a server over the CLI, and was able to do so in using powershell wit the following command:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\ | Select-Object
```