# Missing inetmgr.exe file

Tags: iis

I'm a newbie here and have found some of the material really useful. However, I can't seem to resolve this issue: I'm running Windows 7 Professional and don't have an inetmgr.exe file in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv. I have a number of  iis... files but no inetmgr.exe file.

The bigger picture is that I'm trying to get Apache and PHP working on my laptop and am going round in circles trying to get Localhost to work. I keep getting "Webpage cannot be found" and searching the net has led me to believe the inetmgr.exe file might be key to resolving the problem. That and port 80 might be involved somewhere....

In case you haven't already picked this detail up, I am way, way, way out of my comfort zone with this but I really need to get this working for a course I'm taking.

Thank in advance for any light you may be able to shed.

Comment: Woah woah woah... You should try and understand what it is you're trying to do before you do it. First of all - pick a Web server. Apache **or** IIS. Not both. Just go get the LAMP windows installer - they make it easy to get right on your feet, and there are hundreds of tutorials that will walk you through.

Comment: If this is for a course, and it's not a core part of what you're supposed to be learning, then you should be asking your instructor for some assistance. Certainly he/she would be willing to help you, if it's something you need to work on a different part of the project.

Comment: Finally, you should be asking a question (the title) about the real problem you're having,  not what you *think* is the cause (the "missing" exe). It will make it easier for others to see the question and want to help. However, this isn't a programming question, and is actually quite off-topic for Stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm a few months down the road now and I've come a long way - I appreciate everything you said here - when you're thrown in the deep end you can't see the wood for the trees (interesting picture of an underwater forest....) Sorry for the late response but thanks very much for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inetmgr.exe is the executable for IIS. If you are trying to just have Apache and PHP work, you can use WAMP server - this will give you everything you need to start developing with PHP. The site is: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

IIS is a web server and Apache is a webserver too. If you want to use Apache, you donèt need to have IIS installed.

Comment: Thanks - apologies for the late response - I didn't get notified of any replies. I'm up and running now and making surprising progress but there's so so much to learn! Thanks again

Answer (score 27):

Install IIS:

Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features on or off -> Check "Internet Information Services". Select next and follow prompts to Install IIS.

For more info, see this Q&A to check for and install IIS, [Check whether IIS is installed or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165053/check-whether-iis-is-installed-or-not)

Answer (score 9):

Since this question is the first Google search result for `inetmgr not found`, and since it can be quite puzzling to not be able to find inetmgr even if the web service seems to be working correctly, I thought I'd annotate it with the most obvious answer for those who actually need the IIS Manager: you have to install the Manager separately from WWW service (it is a separate option to installing IIS WWW service itself).

[Windows 8.x]

1. First, type IIS in the Start page: if you see `Internet Information
   (IIS) Manager`, you are good to go. If not...
2. Go to Control Panel, "Programs and Features", then click "Turn
   Windows features on or off" in the left pane.
3. In the "Windows Features" dialog that pops up, make sure that under
   "Internet Information Services" you have "Web Management Features"
   checked in addition to "World Wide Web Services". (Technically, you
   just need "**IIS Management Console**" under "Web Management Features"
   to be checked).
4. Don't forget to click `OK` in the "Windows Features" dialog. :-)
5. Now go to Step #1 and you should see `Internet Information (IIS)
   Manager` as an available icon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install iis first.

> http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

In windows server 2008 R2 I found IIS Server under Roles, not features