# How to Activate MySQL Database on XAMPP for Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can't access **phpMyAdmin** on **XAMPP for Windows** and the problem must be with **MySQL**, because on the **XAMPP Status**, it says **MySQL database** is **DEACTIVATED**. But on my **XAMPP Control Panel Application**, I've already started **MySQL** and it says **Running**, although I didn't check the **Svc** tick box (Is that necessary?). **How to activate MySQL database so that I can run phpMyAdmin?**

Also, when I open **phpMyAdmin** page, it says :

***Error**

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.*

I've already done a research for an answer to this question, but none of them works for me.

Comment: How do you connect to the MySQL server, on `localhost`? on `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: maybe another process has reserved the default port of 3306, open cmd as admin and try `netstat -aon` to see if any process is `LISTENING` to port 3306

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use MySQL through XAMPP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823189/how-do-i-use-mysql-through-xampp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP only summarys MySQL (Database Server) & Apache (Webserver) in one setup and u can manage them with the xampp starter.

Aftet the successfully installation navigate to your xampp folder and execute the `xampp-control.exe`

Press the start Button at the mysql line.

[image]

Now u started successfully mysql. Now there are 2 different ways to administrate your mysql server and his databases.

But at first u have to set/change the MySQL Root password. Start the Apache server and open at your browser `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. If you didn't deleted anything from the htdocs folder the xampp status page appears. Navigate to security settings and change your mysql root password.

Now after this, you can browse to your phpmyadmin under localhost or download a windows mysql client for example navicat lite or mysql workbench. Install it and log to your mysql server with your new root password.

[image]

Comment: I've started MySQL on the Control Panel, and changed MySQL Root password on the localhost security settings and I've also installed MySQL Workbench but I don't know how to go to the Connection Properties (like the one on your image). Or perhaps I downloaded the wrong program? I downloaded MySQL Workbench from here : http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: You mean download the trial version? I'm downloading from here : http://www.navicat.com/download Which one do I choose? Navicat Premium?

Comment: I've already installed Navicat Premium (Trial Version) and I've opened a dialog box like yours. I typed in my new password that I've set in the Security, but when I pressed Test Connection, it says Access Denied. Do I type in MYSQL Server on the Connection Name?

Comment: Connection Name = Only a name for your saved connection. You can type too abcd it doesn't matter. Important is: Hostname, port, user & pw

Comment: Ok, so I made my own name for the Connection Name that I've never typed before in anywhere (That's OK, right?). And on the Hostname, I typed localhost, Port 3306, User Name root and Password from what I typed in Security. I clicked on Test Connection and it says "Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost' (0)" I changed Host Name into 127.0.0.1 and it says "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Is the MySQL Service running? Which xampp version do you use? You can try http://www.ampps.com/download Ampps. It's like xampp but a little bit smarter & easier in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, the service is running, if what you meant is the MySQL from the XAMPP Control Panel. I use XAMPP 1.7.4. Thank you for your solution and suggestion, but if I could, I wouldn't use XAMPP too. Problem is, this is what my instructor gave my class. And 95% of my classmates can use the XAMPP finely, while I have problems accessing phpMyAdmin. This causes me to lose track in my lessons.

Comment: This is a very old xampp version. Download the newest one, remove the old and try it again. http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp-windows.html

Comment: Really? Thanks for the link! I'll download and install it and see if I can access things without problems. I really hope I can and I'm also hoping for it to be not too different from the old version since my instructor is teaching us using the old one. I hope you won't mind if I ask you for a solution again whenever problem arises. Thanks a bunch, Polymorphin! :)

Comment: Do I need to download BitNami Add-ons for Wordpress? My instructor is actually focusing on making a website out of this and he uses Wordpress. So do I download BitNami for that?

Comment: If you want it you can do it

Comment: Ok, I've just installed XAMPP into my laptop. I noticed I can't run Tomcat. Is that ok? Will it affect anything else? And I've tried to open phpMyAdmin and it worked! Thank you! I'm going to ask my friend to coach me step by step and I hope it won't differ too much from the older version. And I've also downloaded BitNami, but I haven't installed it yet. If it's an add-on, that means we have to install it on top of XAMPP, right? In the XAMPP folder?

Comment: Do you know how to fill in the blanks for BitNami's "Create Admin account"? For a better understanding, you can view it here : http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_for_XAMPP No. 3 and No. 4. According to the link there, I reckon it is ok to leave it blank but when I leave mine blank and click Next, it won't allow me to pass.

Comment: Please open for the Bitnami a new question. If my answer solved your problem mark it please as correct answer :)

Comment: Here's my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449591/how-to-create-admin-account-on-bitnami-wordpress-for-xampp-windows Thanks so much, Polymorphin.