# How to Create Admin Account on BitNami WordPress for XAMPP Windows?

Tags: windows, wordpress, xampp, account, bitnami

I'm trying to install BitNami Wordpress on XAMPP for Windows, but I have a slight problem here. There's this Create Admin Account dialog box on my way through installation and it seems to require me to fill the boxes in. It's asking for Login, My real name, Email address, My existing MySQL password for XAMPP, and Application password. I don't know what kind of password I should type in, since I haven't even typed in any password for anything. I've tried to leave it blank and click Next, but it won't allow me.

For a better understanding of my question, you can view it here, No. 3 and No. 4 : http://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/BitNami_for_XAMPP#What_is_the_XAMPP_MySQL_password.3f

Comment: Did you changed your MySQL password since youve installed XAMPP?

Comment: Since I've installed the newer version XAMPP, no.

Answer (score 0):

for the first password field, you will have to add the password of phpmyadmin (if any).
for the second password and retype password field you will have add the password you want to set for wordpress admin.

Comment: So, you mean I have to register in phpMyAdmin first before I can perfectly install BitNami WordPress?

Comment: And now I get it, the application password refers to the password for BitNami WordPress. Thanks for clearing things up!