# Database does not connect

Tags: php, mysql

I created a database as name checkmate on my XAMPP 1.7.3, but database does not connect; it says: Fatal error: Call to undefined function dd_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\checkmate\index.php on line 16
Here is the code:

### index.php

```
<?php
include ( 'include/global_settings/configure.php' );
include ( INCLUDE_PATH.'global_settings'.DS.'connect.php' );
include ( INCLUDE_PATH_FUNCTTIONS.'genaral.php' );

include ( INCLUDE_PATH_FUNCTTIONS.'disp.php' );
include ( INCLUDE_PATH_FUNCTTIONS.'authentications.php' );
include ( INCLUDE_PATH_FUNCTTIONS.'previledges.php' );
include ( INCLUDE_PATH_FUNCTTIONS.'function.php' );
//include ( INCLUDE_PATH_FUNCTTIONS.'jt_functions.php' );

include ( INCLUDE_PATH_CLASS.'getpage.php' );
include ( INCLUDE_PATH_CLASS.'syntax.php' );


dd_connect("ism");

//getpage::getPID( 'page' );
//getpage::display();

previledge_index();

$page = new getpage;

$page->getPID( 'page' );

include ( INCLUDE_PATH.'menu.php' );
//include ('style/js/print.js');

$page->display();

include( INCLUDE_PATH.'footer.php' ); 

?>
```

---

### configure.php

```
<?php

define('ROOT', 'http://localhost/checkmate/');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'checkmate');

define('INCLUDE_PATH', 'include/');
define('INCLUDE_PATH_FUNCTTIONS', 'functions/');
define('INCLUDE_PATH_CLASS', 'class/');
define('INCLUDE_PATH_HTML', 'html/');
define('CSS_PATH', 'css/');
define('INCLUDE_PATH_PAGES', INCLUDE_PATH.'pages/');

define('DS', '/');
define('DEFAULT_PAGE', 'home');


//define('CONF_ARRAY_FILE', 'array.php');
//define('AUTO_UPDATE', TRUE);

?>
```

---

### connect.php

```
<?
//echo "got it";
//dd_connect();
function dd_connect($db)
    {
    //connecting to mySQL
    mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME);

    //connecting to database
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

    }


function access(){
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
$pass=$_SESSION['pass'];

$query="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user='$user'AND pass='$pass'";
$r=mysql_query($query);
$access=mysql_num_rows($r);

if($access==0)die("You are not logged in");

}

?>
```

Comment: have you included connect.php?

Comment: Make sure your `php.ini` file has `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`. Don't forget to restart Apache after making changes. Also, *something something* mysql extension, *something something* deprecated.

Comment: Please replace <? with <?php if you missed it in your code in connect.php and Check your include path for connect.php in index.php

Comment: Thanks, Phil. Now it says: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\checkmate\include\global_settings\connect.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mysql extention is loaded in php

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If you don't see it, add it to your php.ini file!

Also, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), mysql-functions are deprecated.

Comment: Include the <?php
    phpinfo();
?> but same problem

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Will not solve your problem, it will tell you which extensions are installed and which version of php you have.. Insert it in a new php file and post your output, or tell us if you can see if mysql extension is installed.

Comment: php version: 5.3.1, PHP Extension: 20090626

Comment: Can you see mysql in your phpinfo page? Like this: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/phpinfo-mysql.php

Comment: Then you have to install mysql and edit your php.ini file. You're using xampp, so try the answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419201/how-to-activate-mysql-database-on-xampp-for-windows

Comment: i think i have to change php.ini file, but what i change i couldn't understand

Comment: You can find it in `xampp\php\php.ini`. Change `;extension=php_mysql.dll` to `extension=php_mysql.dll`

Comment: But imo, if you follow the previous link and do whatever the solution tells you to, you should have no problems anymore.

Comment: i can't find extension=php_mysql.dll in my php.ini file

Comment: And you have already tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419201/how-to-activate-mysql-database-on-xampp-for-windows ?