# Access denied when creating database with doctrine, Symfony 4

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I created a new Symfony 4 project and want to create a new database. I'm following [this tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/master/doctrine.html) but can't get it to work. When running

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I always get the same error:

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
    An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user_1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In PDOConnection.php line 50:
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user_1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In PDOConnection.php line 46:
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user_1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Following the tutorial, I configured database url in .env file, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user_1:secretPassword@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
```

My config/packages/doctrine.yaml configuration:

```
parameters:
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Tried everything and nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could possibly troubleshoot with https://stackoverflow.com/q/10299148/2123530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031874/unexpected-exception-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for-user-localh)

Possible reasons of the issue :

- collation of your database
- mysql credentials are invalid

Comment: Thank you, this got me on the right path!
I had development environment setup on this system a while ago. Turns out, reinstalling everything multiple times did not reset my database credentials. Finding old ones took some effort, but it works!

Answer (score 4):

Possibly, your user has no permissions to `CREATE DATABASE` operation.
Grant privileges to your user with `grant CREATE on *.* to 'user_1'@'localhost';` in MySQL console.

Answer (score 0):

Check connection with current credentials.
Example for *nix

```
mysql -uuser_1 -p
```

When check mysql server's port

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `localhost` for `127.0.0.1` in your `.env`(or other .env.*) file.