# Why am I getting a Laravel php artisan migrate error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel and am trying to follow along with an online tutorial. I came to a point where I need to run `php artisan migrate` in the terminal and I get the following error:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = some_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:669
    665|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    666|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a   
    667|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    668|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 669|             throw new QueryException(
    670|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    671|             );
    672|         }
    673| 

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=some_db", "root", "", [])
```

I've tried every solution I could find on here and I've gone into my `php.ini` file to enable different extensions but nothing seems to work. I found a solution that said to try running `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` but I'm using Windows so that's not an option for me. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: first do you have created .env on root ?

do you have mysql installed ?

did you run `php artisan clear`

Comment: I have the .env file that came with the laravel package and I have mysqli that I use with phpmyadmin. I just ran `php artisan clear` but it didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the mysql driver installed, you should make sure that the following variables are assigned in the .ENV file//
Si ya tienes el controlador para mysql instalado, debes asegurarte que en el archivo .ENV estén las siguientes variables asignadas:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql //mysql driver
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1   //connection host
DB_PORT=3306        //mysql port
DB_DATABASE=laravel //database name
DB_USERNAME=root    //database user
DB_PASSWORD=        //database password
```

Comment: Tengo esas variables configuradas y el problema sigue ahí

Comment: "_could not find driver_" suggest that the driver is _not_ installed though

Comment: Intenta hacer la conexión desde consola, puede que sea la conectividad con la Base de datos la que falla ¿En que entorno estás trabajando?
Edito: ¿Instalaste el driver php-mysql correcto para tu versión?

Comment: That was my thinking about the drivers. How do I download the ones that I need if I don't have them?

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini configuration file simply uncomment the extension:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

(**You can find your php.ini file in the php folder where your stack server is installed.**)

If you're on **Windows** make it: extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

If you're on Linux make it: extension=pdo_mysql.so

And do a quick server restart.

If this isn't working for you, you may need to install pdo_mysql extension into your php library.

Comment: I've updated `DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME,` and `DB_PASSWORD` to my personal information before I ran `php artisan migrate` and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: does your database running smoothly ? can you connect to it?

Comment: are you 100% sure for the credentials ?

Comment: run composer install

Comment: I have `composer` installed already. And I'm pretty positive about the credentials and database connection. Is there a sure fire way to double check?

Comment: 1) In your project directory run `composer install`
2) see the updated answer

Comment: I have that extension uncommented already and it's still not working for me for some reason.

Comment: also  php-mysql extension may missing. so maybe also something like: `sudo apt install php7.3-mysql` (change 7.3 whit your php ver)

Comment: I saw the `sudo` solution elsewhere but how can I do that on Windows?

Comment: [hope this solves your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823189/how-do-i-use-mysql-through-xampp)

Comment: please let me know

Comment: I'm still new to back end development and this may be a stupid question but do I need to download something other than phpmyadmin and xampp to see my sql name and password?

Comment: hmm this question is not easy to answer. Do you follow the link that i gave you ? Do you complete all the steps ? if yes ? what is the error message now? are you following any tutorial for what you doing ?