# Restore sql file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I restore it using xampp shell command line its working but when I run it using php not working. Is this because of xampp configuration or something ?

shell script

```
mysql -u root -h localhost < Triggers.sql
```

here's my php code

```
$command='mysql -u root -p is2020_db < Triggers.sql';

exec($command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Running on PHP you should execute using **shell_exec**. Like this :

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('mysql -u root -p is2020_db < Triggers.sql');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

## Another way

> Your MySQL binaries should be somewhere under your XAMPP folder. Look for a /bin folder, and
> you'll find the mysql.exe client around. Let's assume it is in
> c:\xampp\mysql\bin, then you should fireup a command prompt in this
> folder.
>
> That means, fire up "cmd", and type:

```
cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql.exe -u root -p is2020_db < Triggers.sql
```

Reference :
[How do I use MySQL through XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823189/how-do-i-use-mysql-through-xampp)

## Example on Windows

> For those using a Windows OS, I was able to import a large mysqldump file into my local XAMPP installation using this command in **cmd.exe**:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p is2020_db < /path/to/file/Triggers.sql
```

But you have to check if this command is allowed in your host and/or you have to allow this in your server.

Comment: I am using xampp and I search for disable_functions and remove functions and I set safe_mode_exec_dir into off and still not working

Comment: I added more tips that should help you.

Comment: this one still not working on php side that code return empty

Comment: Here's my folder path

C:/xampp/htdocs/myMainFolder/myPhpCode.php
C:/xampp/htdocs/myMainFolder/Triggers.sql

Comment: Try this :

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u root -p is2020_db < C:/xampp/htdocs/myMainFolder/Triggers.sql