# Install IIS Windows features by DISM on windows 10

Tags: windows, dism

According [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh824822(v=win.10)) I am gonna install IIS Windows features inorder to offline mode.

I have mounted my `install.wim` and so on like above link.
But when i run this command :

```
 Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-NonHTTP-Activation /All
```

I got this error:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.16299.15

Image Version: 10.0.16299.125

Enabling feature(s)
[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

this error shows `The source files could not be found.` but when i run this error i got result:

```
 Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Get-Features
```

According some idea i have executed this commands:

```
Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
Dism /Image:C:\test\offline /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

but did not work and I got above error. Someone know what is happen and how can i pass this error?

Answer (score 3):

The OS is unable to get the files required in the given path.

Try it online like this.

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebServerRole
/featurename:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /featurename:IIS-ManagementConsole
```